# How to explore the Sea of Storms in the Present Age?

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-ages

Is there any way to explore the Sea of Storms in the Present Age?

There are two overworld maps in *Oracle of Ages*: Past and Present. I have finished all the dungeons, and have all the items and upgrades. I have explored the entire overworld in the past, and every square of the overworld in the present - except for ONE square, inside the Sea of Storms. There does not appear to be any way in, since the Zoro who guards the entrance only appears in the past. There are no available warp points in this area because nearly everything is in deep water.

It feels as if there was an unusual amount of grinding in this game. There is little satisfaction in only getting *very close* to completion, if you are unable to achieve the full 100%. Several important items (such as two pieces of heart) are not awarded consistently, even after much careful work. Previous games, such as *Link to the Past*, *Link's Awakening*, and *Ocarina of Time* did not do this.

**Having an incomplete overworld map is a huge turn-off at the end of an otherwise fun game.**

Is there no resolution on the first play-through?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article below, it is **not** possible to explore the Sea of Storms in the present unless you are in a Linked Game, due to this being part of a Password-Linked Event:

> In a Linked Game, the Piratians appear in the present instead of the
>   past, meaning the Sea of Storms is explored in the present as well,
>   something that would not otherwise be possible.
>
> https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Linked_Game#Oracle_of_Ages

Therefore, the entire map cannot be explored on the first play-through of *Oracle of Ages*.